# Need to run a function based on conditional

Tags: javascript, readonly

I'm trying to assign a function to a couple of checkboxes, but I only want them added based on a condition, in this case the step number of the form. This is a roundabout way of making the checkboxes readOnly AFTER they have been selected (or not). So, at step 1 I want the user to choose cb1 or cb2, but at step 2 I want to assign the function that will not let the checkboxes values be changed.

What am I doing wrong?

```
function functionOne() {
    this.checked = !this.checked
};
if (document.getElementById("stepNumber").value == 2) {
    document.getElementById("cb1").setAttribute("onkeydown", "functionOne(this)");
    document.getElementById("cb2").setAttribute("onkeydown", "functionOne(this)");
}
```

Comment: What type of element is stepNumber?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the element in an argument, so use that:

```
function functionOne(elem) {
    elem.checked = !elem.checked
};
```

---

You could also use properties:

```
document.getElementById("cb1").onkeydown = functionOne;
document.getElementById("cb2").onkeydown = functionOne;

function functionOne() {
    this.checked = !this.checked
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not on the selection disable the checkbox?

```
Function onCheck(elm)
{
    document.getElementById("cbValue").value = elm.value;
    elm.disabled = true;
}


<input id="cbValue" type="hidden" />
```

Use the hidden input field to allow form to send data back to server.

Comment: I can't disable the checkboxes because then their values aren't posted to the form. I need to be able to actually select the check box, submit the form and then on subsequent steps have that check box set so that the value cannot be changed, but it can't be disabled.

Comment: I see. Sometimes when I have this issue I use hidden input elements to handle this. See my update above.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution that requires jquery but you can use the .click function to disable checkboxes once one is clicked.

Here is a working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/uPsm7/